# Slow response onTouchEvent in Android View with background present

Tags: android

all!
I'm trying to figure out have why I have a slow response in Android View in onTouchEvent method. It's a simple TicTacToe game , i removed all the logic, and only things that concern the problem are left. 
So far The onTouchEvent method gets coordinates and then calls onDraw method which simply draws a circle. The onDraw method also draws the background, which is 960x1280 jpg file with the size of 366 kB. It works but i have a delay between touching the screen and getting the circle drawn. It's a few seconds on emulator and about 0.5 seconds on my Samsung. I noticed that without background it works perfectly. But at the same time  the problem seems to be not in drawing the background. I mean, that if i call invalidate() several times in a row drawing a few more figures, they are all drawn instantly, we have delay only before the first figure. So as I understand somehow onTouchEvent method reacts differently depending if there is a background. 
I've been searching but the only thing i found was to add a 16 ms delay (it is in the code, commented) but it didn't help.
If to take a smaller pic , i have a better response, but i need this big picture to suit different phones.
So in conclusion , the problem is that response time depends on the size of background pic, but at the same time it's not a problem of drawing this big picture, only for onTouchEvent to respose. I am confused -) How can that be? 
Please, help me if you can.

Here is the code:

```
public class GameViewBug extends View {

    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private float touchX;
    private float touchY;

    public GameViewBug(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kletka3);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, 50, mCirclePaint);

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(16);
//        }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` inside `onDraw`? dont you have any lint warnings there?

Comment: I believe @alex-shutov pointed out why this is happening. So i would suggest you do the same. Call the decodeResource somewhere else and send the bitmap to your GameViewBug object and then call invalidate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you perform heavy computational operation on main thread in method, which is called very often:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kletka3)
```

You should load that resource once (suggest using Glide library for displaying images), and do all computations on background thread.

Comment: So far, i simply put  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kletka3)

Comment: So far, i simply put  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kletka3) into the init() method and it started to work perfectly ! Thank you! Maybe I'll have  to learn more about this glide library but for now the problem is solved. It is still not quite clear for me though, why it worked well when i was calling invalidate() several times in a row, but it's just a curiosity , it doesn't matter much now. Anyway , Thank you all ! Thank you , my friends! You helped me very much